# Initialize and Populate a dataTable in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datatables

I'm working with a C# MVC project and trying to use the [DataTables plugin](http://dataTables.net).

In trying to populate the table with test data I wind up getting an error at run-time that `.dataTable` is not a function.

It appears that I am including the js properly and I can see that the js loads in firebug. Hopefully someone can spot the error.

```
    <body>
    <div id="dynamic">

</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

       function populateTable(json){
           $('#dynamic').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');
           $('#example').dataTable({
            "aaData":[
                ["Trident","IE4.0","Win95",4,"X"]
            ],
            "aoColumns": [
                {"sTitle":"Engine"},
                {"sTitle": "Browser" },
                {"sTitle": "Platform" },
                {"sTitle": "Version" , "sClass":"center" },
                {"sTitle": "Grade" , "sClass": "center"}
            ]
           });
       };

       function getCampaigns() {
           $.ajax({
                url : '/ADKTest/GetCampaigns',
            }).done(function(response) {
                populateTable(response);
                alert("Worked");
            }).error(function(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Didn't Work");
            });
        };

        getCampaigns();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I can't replicate (just using your populateTable function). It works fine for me.  What is the reason behind building the table like that? Where are you using the json variable in `populateTable`?

Comment: eventually im using that json var to populate table.... i actually figured it out just now though ... i was including jquery and dataTable js files in the wrong order ... oops ...

Comment: Also please consider NOT doing your javascript like that and instead include jquery and other scripts just before the `</body>` tag... like `Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>` and then your code on the page would look like `@section Scripts {
<script>$(document).ready(function () {`